# Concatenate + Count if with a dynamic range

Tags: vba, concatenation, countif

I need to write this on the second line of the first column (A2) and then autofill until the end of the spreedsheet.

`=CONCATENATE(D1;".";COUNTIF($D$1:D1, D1))`

The fisrt "D1" needs to be fix, because on the second line the code must be "`=CONCATENATE(D1;".";COUNTIF($D$1:D2, D2))`"

Its a large amount of data and Excel wont handle it by formula, so I need to do it with VBA.

What I'm trying to do:

I have a list of names that appear more than once. I need the name to be written with the number of times it has appeared so far. For example:

```
Miriam  -- Miriam.1
Maria   -- Maria.1
Thiago  -- Thiago.1
Maria   -- Maria.2
Cloe    -- Cloe.1
Maria   -- Maria.3
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What do you mean, "Excel won't handle it by formula"?  Are you getting an error?  Have you tried dragging the formula down or copy pasting it into the range?

Comment: I mean the spreedsheet has 1048576 lines, so when i try dragging the formula down, it just crash!

Comment: Sorry about my english, by the way!

Comment: You actually have a million rows of data in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes.. Its the max excel accepts. 
Its big data! (=

Comment: I'd love to understand what the purpose of this is.

Comment: For such huge amount of data, such an operation will be very slow with VBA as well. Excel might not be the appropriate tool for this. If I had to do it, I would save my data as CSV and write some specific C++ program. Besides, note that the first `D1` in your second formula (for the second row) is `D2` not `D1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A2 = "=CONCATENATE(D2;".";COUNTIF($D$1:D2, D2))"
and A3 = "=CONCATENATE(D3;".";COUNTIF($D$1:D3, D3))"

try this, 100k runs in a couple of minutes
1048576 is still running after 18minutes

if you are desperate for the data you can run this in batches

lastrow = 100000, for i =2 to lastrow

lastrow = 200000, for i =100001 to lastrow

etc
I think given enough time it will run all at once

im on 64bit office 2016 with 4gb ram btw.

```
Sub test()

Dim namerange As Range
Dim countrange As Range
Dim i As Double
Dim lastrow As Double
lastrow = 50000

Set namerange = Sheet1.Range("D1:D" & 1048576)
Set countrange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & 1048576)

For i = 2 To lastrow

    countrange(i, 1) = namerange(i, 1) & "." & _
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(namerange.Range("A1:A" & i), namerange(i, 1))

Next i

Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(countrange.Rows.Count, 1).Cells.Value = countrange.Cells.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! 
Of course!
Is there any way of making it faster? After the first 100.000 rows, it crashes.

Comment: are you able to sort the data? if you can get the same names together in blocks it would be helpful. if you need to keep the same order then create a new column call it sortorder this columns starts at 1 each rows goes up 1.

Comment: then sort by name, secondary sort by sortorder.

Answer (score 1):

Runs full list in 90 seconds,
relies on column E being blank, this will destroy any data in column E

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim temprange As Range
    Dim i As Double
    Dim nameCounter As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Double
    lastrow = 1048576
    nameCounter = 1
    Set temprange = Sheet1.Range("A1:D" & lastrow)
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        temprange(i, 5) = i
    Next i

    temprange.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 5)).Sort Key1:=Cells(1, 4), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Key2:=Cells(1, 5), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If temprange(i, 4) <> temprange(i - 1, 4) Then
            nameCounter = 1
        Else
            nameCounter = nameCounter + 1
        End If
        temprange(i, 1) = temprange(i, 4) & "." & nameCounter
    Next i
    temprange.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 5)).Sort Key1:=Cells(1, 5), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    temprange.Columns(5).Clear

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```